# Induction proof clarification. n ≥ m can be expressed as 3a + 5b + 7c for positive integers a, b and c

Tags: proof-explanation, induction

**Question**

Prove that there exists an odd integer m such that every odd integer n with n ≥ m can
be expressed as 3a + 5b + 7c for positive integers a, b and c.

**Proof**

We show for every odd integer n ≥ 21 that there exist positive integers a, b and c such that
n = 3a + 5b + 7c.
Proof. We proceed by induction. First, observe that 21 = 3·3 + 5·1 + 7·1 and 23 = 3·2 + 5·2 + 7·1.
Assume for an odd integer k, where k ≥ 23, that k = 3a + 5b + 7c for positive integers a, b
and c. We show that this is the case for k + 2. If a ≥ 2, then k + 2 = 3(a − 1) + 5(b + 1) + 7c;
while if b ≥ 2, then k +2= 3a + 5(b − 1) + 7(c + 1). Suppose that a = b = 1. Since k ≥ 23, it
follows that c ≥ 2. Therefore, k + 2 = 3 · 4 + 5 · 1 + 7(c − 1). By the Principle of Mathematical
Induction, it follows for every odd integer n ≥ 21 that there exist positive integers a, b and c such
that n = 3a + 5b + 7c.

**My question**

My question is about the very last step, where it says "k + 2 = 3 · 4 + 5 · 1 + 7(c − 1)". Where did the 4 and 1 come from, especially 4? I would understand if they were chosen to satisfy the requirement of the question, but k + 2 = 3 · 4 + 5 · 1 + 7(c − 1) would equal 24 for c = 2, and I was under the impression that we need to make k + 2 = 25.

Comment: It's basically $k+2=3(a+3)+5b+7(c-1)$, which is applied to the case where $c\ge2$.

Comment: It is $3 \times 4 + 5 \times 1 +7(c-1) =(3 \times 1 + 3 \times 3)+5 +7 c -7=3+5 +7c+9-7=(3+5+7 c)+2=k+2$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But it would still be 24 if c = 2? And it was assumed that k ≥ 23, so shouldn't k + 2 come out to 25, in the case k = 23?

Comment: $23=3(2)+5(2)+7(1)=6+10+7=23$; thus $a, b \ge 2$ and the two first subcases apply: either (i) $3(1)+5(3)+7=3+15+7=25$, or (ii) $3(2)+5(1)+7(2)=6+5+14=25$. For $25$ the third case does not apply, because for $23$ we have that both $a$ and $b$ are not $1$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you! Which 3rd case are you referring to though?